# SQL Create View for Calendar

Tags: sql, calendar, transpose

I'm looking for some ideas to create view calendar from 1 table in SQL.
Requirement is as follow.
Please give me advice how to transpose by number of digit inside 1 cell of data.

[image: Table A]

Table A contains Year_JAHR, Days_MON1 ~ Days_MON12 (January~December)
Value inside Days_MON1~Days_MON12 :

- 1 means working day
- 0 means holiday
- Digit 1 means 1st day of the month, digit 2 means 2nd day of the month, etc

I would like to create view as follow :

| Year_JAHR | Month | Date | WorkingDay |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ |
| 2022 | 1 | 31 | 1 |

Comment: Use a recursive cte. But how do you know the WorkingDays?

Comment: Please post data as text not images. What is your DBMS?

Comment: @jarlh I got working days from SAP system (Factory calendar). Assuming we got the data into a table as the picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S5xy.png , I would like to create the view to make it easier to be read.